# youtube_it gem not working in Rails console or IRB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube

I installed the youtube_it version(2.0.1) gem but I cannot seem to get it to work in the rails console or in irb. I follow all the steps shown [here](https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it) for establishing a client, but when I perfore the query:

```
client.videos_by(:query => "penguin")
```

I get

```
 <YouTubeIt::Response::VideoSearch:0x101f1c460 @max_result_count=nil, @updated_at=nil, @offset=nil, @feed_id=nil, @videos=[], @total_result_count=nil>
```

I have tried it from inside my App's directory and out; with irb and rails console and I get the same thing every time. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a correct developer key when creating a client? You can get a developer key [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard).

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me, did you try whit the last version of the gem (2.1.3)?, I'm using this and works nice

```
irb(main):004:0> client = YouTubeIt::Client.new
=> #<YouTubeIt::Client:0x007fc5a0116a58>
irb(main):005:0> client.videos_by(:query => "penguin").videos.count
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?max-results=25&q=penguin&start-index=1&v=2
=> 25
```

tell me if this works for you

cheers!